# Jenkins Валидация Git

Tags: git, jenkins, http-status-code-500

Во время конфигурации *джобы* необходимо подключить *Git* плагин.
В раздел "**Управление исходным кодом**" при выборе раздела *Git* просит вставить ссылку на **Git репозиторий**.

При вставке любой ссылки(*с .git, без этого, ssh версии*) спустя время возникает "**Ошибка обработки запроса**"

Постоянно вылетает эта ошибка.

```
An internal error occurred during form field validation (HTTP 500). Please reload the page and if the problem persists, ask the administrator for help.
```

В консоли же вот такое:
`POST http://localhost:8080/job/PrivateProject/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig/checkUrl 500 (Server Error)`

Бьюсь над ошибкой уже больше часа.

Comment: Коллега, приветствую. Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. Удалось ли тебе разобраться в причине данной ошибки?

Comment: для проверки стоит запустить ещё один, «чистый» экземпляр jenkins-а (последней опубликованной версии) с минимумом дополнительных плагинов, и проделать в нём то, что вы описали в вопросе. а дальше действовать, исходя из результата проверки.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто переустановил Дженкинс и все взлетело. Проблема была в некорректной установке.